# What is the type 'seq<'a>' in f#?

Tags: types, f#

I'm new to F# (python programmer), and very confused with an error I am getting. I have an exercise to calculate an infinite sequence from the Nilakantha series (pi estimation). This is my code so far:

```
   let piSeq x =
      let sum = 0m
      let bool = true
      let calculation x = (4m / (2m*x*(2m*x+1m)*(2m*x+2m)))
      seq {
         for b in 0..x do
            let x = x |> decimal
            if b=0 then let sum = sum + 3m
                        yield sum
            else if bool = true
                 then let sum = sum + (calculation x)
                      let bool = false
                      yield sum
                 else let sum = sum - (calculation x)
                      let bool = true
                      yield sum

      }

    Seq.iter (printf "%A ") (Seq.take 1000 piSeq)
```

This code is giving me the following error:

```
error FS0001: The type 'int -> seq<int>' is not compatible with the type 'seq<'a>'
```

My question is, what is 'seq<'a>'? How can I convert int to 'a, so this code doesn't fail?

Thanks!

Comment: Seq,take expects an int and a sequence. You're giving an int and a function (piSeq is a function that expects an int). So it should be  (Seq.take 1000 (piSeq provideSomeIntHere)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seq<'a>` in an alias for `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`. You may find more C#-oriented documentation of it. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netcore-3.1

This represents a sequence of values of type `'a` where `'a` can be any type. This means you can iterate over the values, but you can not make other assumptions about the collection. All other .NET collections inherit from `seq`. A `seq` may be a "materialized" list or array, or it can be a "lazy" generator that fetches values from somewhere. You can even use it to create an infinite sequence.

The error message you are seeing is saying that a function that takes an `int` parameter and returns a `seq<int>` (`int -> seq<int>`) is not the same as a `seq<'a>`.